# PHP/MySQL - Print rows when id matches

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have two tables in MySQL Database, namely:

`maintenance : name(primary key), url, and description`

`feeds : feed_id(primary key), feed_name(foreign key reference name), feed_url, feed_notes`

When i select the name from list `<ul><li>` it suppose to print the corresponding information related to the selected name.

Any idea how to do it?

**Expected Outcome**

[image: Expected Output]

This is what I've done so far

**LIST:**

```
<div id="cssmenu">
            <?php
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $database = "rssfeed";

            $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
            if (!$connect) {
                die("Cannot connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            mysqli_select_db($connect, $database);

            $sql = "SELECT * from maintenance";
            $data = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);


            if (mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
                    ?>
                    <ul id="record<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
                        <li class="name"></li>
                        <li><span><a href="rssoutput" name="title"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>

        </div>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<div id ="rssoutput">
            <?php
                $name = $_POST['name'];

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM feeds, maintenance WHERE feed_name=$name";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

                $link = $title = $notes = array();

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $link = $row['feed_url'];
                        $title = $row['feed_title'];
                        $notes = $row['feed_notes'];

                        echo "<a id=title href='" . $link . "'>" . $title . "</a>";
                        echo "<p>" . $notes . "</p>";
                        echo "<hr>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

### AJAX

**getrss.php**

```
    <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "rssfeed";

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$connect) {
    die("Cannot connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_select_db($connect, $database);

$name = $_GET['name'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM feeds, maintenance WHERE feed_name='$name' AND name='$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

$link = $title = $notes = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $link = $row['feed_url'];
    $title = $row['feed_title'];
    $notes = $row['feed_notes'];

    echo "<a id=title href='" . $link . "'>" . $title . "</a>";
    echo "<p>" . $notes . "</p>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

**action.js**

```
    function showRSS(id) {
    var str = $("#record" + id + ".name").html();
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("rssoutput").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getrss.php?id=" + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("rssoutput").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

**myfeeds.php**

```
            <div id="cssmenu">
            <?php
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $database = "rssfeed";

            $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
            if (!$connect) {
                die("Cannot connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            mysqli_select_db($connect, $database);

            $sql = "SELECT * from maintenance";
            $data = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);


            if (mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
                    ?>
                    <ul id="record<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
                        <li class="name"></li>
                        <li><span><a  href="#rssoutput" name="title" onclick="showRSS(<?php echo $row['name'] ?>)"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>

        </div>
```

**I know my codes doesn't make sense. For me at least, cause I don't have any idea how to start working on it** So if you guys can help me out, It's really really really appreciated

Comment: alternatively, you could utilize an ajax operation for this, just use that `output` on click on those list, then load the response on the right side.

Comment: @Ghost i did it as an option but it didn't work.

Comment: Can u post your optional work code pls!

Comment: @SUDHIR can you check it ? :o

Comment: $name is a string, right?

Answer (score 0):

It think there's no problem with your code.

But I check that in getrss.php you use $name = $_GET['name']; while in your action.js you make request with getrss.php?id=

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Only one problem syntax in my js

```
    function showRSS(name) {
    var str = $("#record" + id + ".name").html();
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("rssoutput").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getrss.php?name=" + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("rssoutput").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

instead of id, i change it to name :)